# Meaning of 押し殺す

Tags: meaning

> 「ちょっとどいて」
> ハーマイオニーは**押し殺した**ような声でそう言うと ...
> Move over, Hermione snarled

When I first read the above I translated it roughly as "Hermione spoke as though she would kill *someone*", i.e. I gathered that she was speaking in an angry voice.  And, indeed,  押し殺す apparently has the meaning "to crush to death". But it also seems to have a meaning of "to subdue/muffle" one's voice.

Now, the English word 'snarl' suggests both anger and a subdued voice so 押し殺す seems like a clever translation, but I wonder if it really is. Are both these qualities implied in the Japanese sentence, or does one meaning take precedence? How is 押し殺す most likely to be used in everyday speech?

Comment: If 押し殺す literally meant *to crush to kill*, 押し殺**した**ような声 would mean "as though she **had killed** someone," though.

Comment: It’s honestly not a great translation, in the sense that it doesn’t maintain the nuance of the English. Snarl has a strong sense of anger, and 押し殺した声 is totally missing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the first meaning of [押し殺す](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%8A%BC%E6%AE%BA%E3%81%99/#jn-30997) is crushing someone to death, in daily speech (luckily), it almost always means #2:

> ２ 感情などをおさえつけて、外へ表れないようにする。「笑いを—・す」「—・したような声」

So yes, 押し殺したような声 would be the most frequently used instance of 押し殺す. It definitely means *muffled/subdued* voice, but to me, it doesn't have to be anger that is suppressed. It means the speaker trying to be less emotional (I mean, she can be angry, but it can be something else).

I guess this is just because it's very hard to 'press and kill' (I can't really imagine how it's done). If someone is killed in an accident (e.g. in a factory, by machine misoperation), it would be 圧死{あっし}する.

---

For comparison, 刺し殺す/殴り殺す/絞め殺す/打ち殺す/轢{ひ}き殺す are all used for really killing someone (the last one is to run over someone by vehicle).